# adding new variables to a data frame using dplyr select and mutate functions in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

Please let me know if this is a duplicate. I've looked over Stack and have found questions that are similar, but don't quite answer my question. I'm a beginner, so I appreciate anyone's help.

I am trying to add yearly summary variables to a data frame of monthly data (i.e, summing across rows). Here is an example data frame with limited monthly data.

```
df <- data.frame("Jan.2012" = c(1, 4, 5, 6), "Feb.2012" = c(3, 5, 7, 9),
 "Jan.2013" = c(6, 8, 9, 10), "Feb.2013" = c(7, 5, 11, 13), "Jan.2014" = c(6, 8, 9, 11), 
 "Feb.2014" = c(7, 3, 5, 9))
```

The new variables would be named TotalYr2012, TotalYr2013, etc. For example, TotalYr2012 = c(4, 9, 12, 15), etc.

I am trying to iterate over a for loop (not best practice I know) to generate these variables. I know I am doing some things wrong with the assign statement as well as I get an error.

```
for (i in 2012:2014) {
  varname <- paste("TotalYr", i, sep = "")
    assign(df$varname, df %>% select(contains("i")) %>% 
     mutate(varname = sum()))
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$` doesn't work with variables, you need to use `[` or `[[`. (But you have several other problems too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid `for-loop` by using `tidyr::gather` and `zoo::yearmon` functions to calculate summary for each year.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df %>% gather(Date, value) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.yearmon(Date,"%b.%Y")) %>%
  group_by(Year = year(Date)) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(value)) %>%
  spread(Year, Total)

# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#     `2012` `2013` `2014`
# *   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1   40.0   69.0   58.0
```

Comment: I appreciate this. I must not have explained myself clearly. I want to sum across rows of df as each record represents something such Product X sales in Jan. 2012, Product Y sales in Feb. 2013, etc. So I would want to see all of Product X sales for the months of 2012, etc. However, seeing this code did help me understand a dplyr approach to get to the answer i wanted, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You've got a lot of problems.

1. `$` doesn't work with variables. Use `[` or `[[` instead. [See this R-FAQ for additional info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222286/903061). Also your indentation is messy, let's make it consistent:

   ```
   for (i in 2012:2014) {
     varname <- paste("TotalYr", i, sep = "")
     assign(df[[varname]], df %>% select(contains("i")) %>% 
       mutate(varname = sum()))
   }
   ```
2. `assign` isn't needed, just use `<-` (or `=`). You should almost never use `assign()`.

   ```
   for (i in 2012:2014) {
     varname <- paste("TotalYr", i, sep = "")
     df[[varname]] <- df %>% select(contains("i")) %>% 
       mutate(varname = sum()))
   }
   ```
3. `"i"` is a string, it's value is always the letter `"i"`, just like the value of `2` is always `2`. Even in `contains()` you want to use the *value* you have assigned to the *object `i`* (though *that value* does need to be a string, that is, it needs to be of class `character`):

   ```
   for (i in 2012:2014) {
     varname <- paste("TotalYr", i, sep = "")
     df[[varname]] <- df %>% select(contains(as.character(i))) %>% 
       mutate(varname = sum()))
   }
   ```
4. `mutate` and `select` return data frames, which means your code is trying to assign a one-column data frame do `df[[varname]]`. We want to assign just a column vector, not a whole data frame. So we pull out the column vector, with `dplyr::pull`

   ```
   for (i in 2012:2014) {
     varname <- paste("TotalYr", i, sep = "")
     df[[varname]] <- df %>% select(contains(as.character(i))) %>% 
       mutate(varname = sum())) %>%
       pull()
   }
   ```
5. Type `sum()` in your console - you get `0`. You need give something to `sum()`. Let's get rid of `mutate` entirely and just `sum` the `pull`ed vector, this way we don't have to worry about its name:

   ```
   for (i in 2012:2014) {
     varname <- paste("TotalYr", i, sep = "")
     df[[varname]] <- df %>% select(contains(as.character(i))) %>% 
       pull %>% sum
   }
   ```
6. Okay, it sort of works now. But you're adding these new values to the old data frame, which has a bunch of rows. The new values are just single values, so they're "recycled", repeated on every row of the data frame. Let's create a new `result` data frame instead which will have just one row for our result:

   ```
   result = list()
   for (i in 2012:2014) {
     varname <- paste("TotalYr", i, sep = "")
     result[[varname]] <- df %>% select(contains(as.character(i))) %>% 
       pull %>% sum
   }
   result = as.data.frame(result)
   result
   #   TotalYr2012 TotalYr2013 TotalYr2014
   # 1          24          36          24
   ```
7. Now it works, and gives a working solution. However, it is still messy. `for` loops usually aren't necessary. We have much better tools for tidying data.

   ```
   # See MKR's answer. It's the way you should actually do this.
   ```

Comment: Fantastic explanation, which covers almost everything. Probably your answer is much helpful to beginners than mine.

Comment: My answer covers what is wrong with OP's approach, your answer covers the right approach. I think they complement each other well.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I learned a lot of general principles for future projects from just reading the principles you shared.

Comment: However, when I run this code in RStudio, result returns a data frame with 0 rows and 0 columns. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I forgot to change one last `df` to `result` in #6. Fixed now.